# Problems with realm after gradle update

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, realm, android-studio-3.1

After update AndroidStudio to 3.1 and gradle to 3.1.0 I cannot build my project. I got this error:

`Could not determine artifacts for io.realm:realm-android-library:5.0.0: Skipped due to earlier error`

I have already tried:

1. Clean/Rebuild project
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. gradle clean assemble --refresh-dependencies

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Well what is the earlier error?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I had only this error

Comment: No, you are having other errors previously to this one. Check the gradle console and stuff.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ok, but I will answer you tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't know how but it works today

Comment: Then it was probably that JCenter was down yesterday and returned bad gateway every now and then